# Mobile game winning message issue - alert box

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, tic-tac-toe

I have made a simple TicTacToe game for a university project, and it works using HTML and JavaScript.
It work fine when viewing on a desktop, but on mobile there is an issue.
On mobile the final winning piece does not show up when you win, but everything else like the alert box does.

You can try it out here -- http://stuffmadeby.me/test/tictactoe/ -- if view this page on a mobile smartphone.

Is there any way to fix this?

Strange how it works on desktop but not on mobile, as I want to package this up using PhoneGap to make it into a simple app.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#messages').hide();
    var currentPlayer=1;
    square=new Array(3)
    square[0]=new Array(3);
    square[1]=new Array(3);
    square[2]=new Array(3);

    var Ximg = $('<img />').attr('src','images/x.png');
    var Oimg = $('<img />').attr('src','images/o.png');

    samego=false;
    endgame=false;

    $('.square').click(function() {
        samego=false;
        input=$(this).attr('id');
        arrayindex=input.split("");
        x=arrayindex[0];
        y=arrayindex[1];
            if(square[x][y]=='X'||square[x][y]=='O') {
                $('#messages').html("That square has already been filled! try again.");
                samego=true;
            } else {
                currentPlayer==1 ? square[x][y]='X' : square[x][y]='O';
                currentPlayer==1 ? $('#'+input).html('<img src="images/x.png"/>') :
                $('#'+input).html('<img src="images/o.png"/>');
            }
            checkStatus();
    }); /* ends .square click function */

    function checkStatus() {
        if(
            square[0][0]=='X'&&square[0][1]=='X'&&square[0][2]=='X'||
            square[0][0]=='X'&&square[1][1]=='X'&&square[2][2]=='X'||
            square[1][0]=='X'&&square[1][1]=='X'&&square[1][2]=='X'||
            square[2][0]=='X'&&square[2][1]=='X'&&square[2][2]=='X'||
            square[0][1]=='X'&&square[1][1]=='X'&&square[2][1]=='X'||
            square[2][0]=='X'&&square[1][1]=='X'&&square[0][2]=='X'||
            square[0][2]=='X'&&square[1][2]=='X'&&square[2][2]=='X'||
            square[0][0]=='X'&&square[1][0]=='X'&&square[2][0]=='X'
    )
    {
        $('#messages').show().html("Player 1 wins!");
        alert("Player 1 wins! Click to reset!");
        reinitialise();
        endgame=true;
    }
        if(
            square[0][0]=='O'&&square[0][1]=='O'&&square[0][2]=='O'||
            square[0][0]=='O'&&square[1][1]=='O'&&square[2][2]=='O'||
            square[1][0]=='O'&&square[1][1]=='O'&&square[1][2]=='O'||
            square[2][0]=='O'&&square[2][1]=='O'&&square[2][2]=='O'||
            square[0][1]=='O'&&square[1][1]=='O'&&square[2][1]=='O'||
            square[2][0]=='O'&&square[1][1]=='O'&&square[0][2]=='O'||
            square[0][2]=='O'&&square[1][2]=='O'&&square[2][2]=='O'||
            square[0][0]=='O'&&square[1][0]=='O'&&square[2][0]=='O'
    )
    {
        $('#messages').html("Player 2 wins!");
        alert("Player 2 wins! Click to reset!");
        reinitialise();
        endgame=true;
    }

    var filled=0;
    for(x=0;x<3;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<3;y++) {
            if(square[x][y]=='X'||square[x][y]=='O') {
                filled++;
            }
        }
    } /* ends var filled */

    if(!samego&&!endgame) {
        currentPlayer==1 ? currentPlayer=2 : currentPlayer=1;
    } /* ends if */

    if(filled==9) {
        $('#messages').html("It's a draw!");
        alert("It's a draw! Click to reset!");
        reinitialise();
    } /* ends filled==9 */

    endgame=false;
    $('#player').html('Current Player = Player '+currentPlayer);

    } /* ends function check status */

    function reinitialise() {
        $('#messages').hide();
        $('#messages').html('');    
        square[0][0]=''; $('#00').html('');
        square[0][1]=''; $('#01').html('');
        square[0][2]=''; $('#02').html('');
        square[1][0]=''; $('#10').html('');
        square[1][1]=''; $('#11').html('');
        square[1][2]=''; $('#12').html('');
        square[2][0]=''; $('#20').html('');
        square[2][1]=''; $('#21').html('');
        square[2][2]=''; $('#22').html('');
        currentPlayer=1;
    } /* ends function reintialise */

}); /* ends whole function */
```

Comment: So you know, `<!--` and `-->` are not comments in Javascript.

Comment: Using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) on your code found the following: Missing a semicolon at ln 4 (square=new Array(3)), Need to wrap `X && Y` statements in parenthesis (i.e. `(square[0][0]=='X'&&square[0][1]=='X'&&square[0][2]=='X')`), There are 3 instances of `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`, at lines 25, 26 and 76. I used JSLint global vars: `jQuery $ Implied global: $ document` and directive: `/*jslint eqeq: true, plusplus: true, undef: true, unparam: true, sloppy: true, vars: true, white: true, browser: false, devel: true */`. Hope that helps!

Comment: External links tend to die over time, which means that this question will lose value if others visit it later. Can you produce a small, self-contained fragment that reproduces your problem? If so, please put that into your original question instead of the link.